# Validate password and give dynamic alert while Typing

Tags: validation, passwords, aurelia

I am using Aurelia Framework .I want that when user typing a password then Dynamic Alerts/console should show to user while typing .

1- Must Contain 1 Capital Alphabets.
2-Must Contain 1 small Alphabets.
3- Must contain 1 Numeric digit
4- Must contain 1 Special Character

If user missing any of them then user should show dynamic message.Like if User use Capital and small alphabets then message should to use numeric and Special characters too and so on.Here is my regex

```
"^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])))(?=.{6,})"
```

Comment: Validation should check if all conditions in Regex are meet or not .

Comment: it will be better to break down this monster regex to multiple little checks. then you will have control over what rules a specific string meet/break - and can show your messages accordingly. consider using the [official aurelia validation plugin](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/validation/) to better handle rules and custom errors associated with them.

Comment: yes I did it same and its working .If i want to show all message at same time and hide/remove message if condition meet then what to do ?